# PayPal Instant Payment Notification IPN with empty POST

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

I use paypal subscriptions (hosted buttons)

```
auto-return for Website Payments is on
Payment Data Transfer is on
success, fail and notify url are different
extra params for button are:
rm=2
notify_url=<url>
sra=1
rest in PayPal is default.
```

all works in pro and sandbox

but POST request from IPN come with empty data every time.

- sandbox IPN works.
- request handling is ok - tested with curl.
- history of IPN messages on paypal is ok.

did I forgot something ?

please confirm or reject PayPal problems on your IPN.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I set encoding for IPN to UTF-8
and it works now

my accont => my profile => my selling tools => language encoding